# Цикл завершается раньше, чем хотелось бы

Tags: java, алгоритм, генераторы

Сколько попыток понадобится сделать компьютеру чтобы подобрать из рандомных букв слово которое вы ввели?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // будет формировать новое слово из рандомных букв
    Random random = new Random(); // великий псевдорандом
    String myWord = reader.readLine(); // ваше слово
    int wordLenght = myWord.length(); // количество символов в вашем слове
    int counterOfMyShances = 0; // счётчик попыток
    char[] alphabetArr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}; 

do { // выполняем процесс формирования слова в цикле 
for (int i = 0; i < wordLenght; i++) {
    int randomlLeter = random.nextInt(alphabetArr.length); // извлекаем случайную букву
    stringBuilder.append(alphabetArr[randomlLeter]); // формируем строку из букв
    counterOfMyShances ++;  
}
}while (myWord.equals(stringBuilder));  //всё вышеперечисленное выполняем до тех пор пока введённое и сгенерированное слова совпадут
     System.out.println(counterOfMyShances );
```

Цикл "do while" выполняет блок "do" далее сравнивает результат с блоком "while" и если второй блок не отвечает "Да, это try" начинает процесс с начала. Так?
 Мой код генерирует слово длиной строго равной длине введённого слова и дальше завершает процесс несмотря на то что слова не совпадают.
Что я упустил? скажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;// будет формировать новое слово из рандомных букв
        Random random = new Random(); // великий псевдорандом
        String myWord = reader.readLine(); // ваше слово
        int counterOfMyShances = 0; // счётчик попыток
        char[] alphabetArr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

        do { // выполняем процесс формирования слова в цикле 
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < myWord.length(); i++) {
                int randomlLeter = random.nextInt(alphabetArr.length); // извлекаем случайную букву
                stringBuilder.append(alphabetArr[randomlLeter]); // формируем строку из букв
                counterOfMyShances++;
            }
        } while (!myWord.equals(stringBuilder.toString()));  //всё вышеперечисленное выполняем до тех пор пока введённое и сгенерированное слова совпадут
        System.out.println(counterOfMyShances);
    }

}
```

Comment: while (!myWord.equals(stringBuilder)) - это верно, но это не все. проблема еще и в StringBuilder. Поскольку экземпляр этого класса один он бесконечно накапливает случайные символы. Таким образом, если с первого раза комбинация не угадана, то в дальнейшем это не происходит никогда. а еще обратите внимание на условие (!myWord.equals(stringBuilder.toString())). вы сравниваете экземпляр класса String  и экземпляр класса StringBuilder , что некорректно.

Comment: Этот текст должен быть написан в ответе, а не в комментарии :)

Comment: Не лучше ди обнулять stringBuilder, чем каждый раз создавать заново?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду под "обнулять"?

Comment: Удалять содержимое, присваивать пустую строку, и т.п.

Comment: Если вы заранее знаете ожидаемую пропускную способность StringBuilder, каждый раз создание нового должно быть таким же быстрым, как установка новой длины (обнуление). Это также поможет сборщику мусора, поскольку каждый StringBuilder будет относительно недолговечным, и gc оптимизирован для этого.

Comment: Если вы не знаете емкость, повторное использование того же StringBuilder может быть быстрее. Каждый раз, когда вы превышаете емкость при добавлении, должен быть выделен новый массив поддержки, а предыдущий контент должен быть скопирован. Повторно используя тот же StringBuilder, он достигнет необходимой емкости после некоторых итераций и после этого не будет никакого копирования.

Comment: Но это тонкие материи. Не думаю, что это важно для данного конкретного примера... Хотя обсуждение безусловно полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Относительно ошибок приводящие к некорректной работе алгоритма вам уже ответили, но я бы хотел обратить ваше внимание на крайнюю не оптимальность самого алгоритма.

Зачем в сравнении участвует регистр в момент поиска набора букв? Даже для ужесточения совпадения почему не применить разность регистров уже на этапе когда само слово совпадает и уже в рамках много меньшего кол-ва комбинаций подбирать регистр?

Если даже отбросить сам факт что заглавные буквы употребляются в именах только в начале имени, и допустить ее существование в разных позициях имени, все равно такая маленькая поправка в алгоритме сузит кол-во возможных комбинаций в поиске нужного имени, мягко говоря, существенно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за поправку в отношении некорректной работы моего алгоритма, но в мои планы не входит сделать его как можно более быстрым и мене ресурсозатратным. Мне интересно сколько попыток сделает комп прежде чем слова совпадут. P.S. Относительно ошибок. Я применил все полученые мной здесь советы но результат не изменился. Я добавил "!" в сравнение равенства, обнулил СтрингБилдер. Результат не изменился, программа подбирает из рандомных букв буквосочетание равное по длине заказанному слову и выходит из цикла(не смотря на то, что слова не равны)

Comment: Спасибо всем отозвамшимся! код от Дмитрий-  отлично работает. Пойду изучать его и сравнивать с своим.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш цикл выполняется столько раз, сколько раз два слова равны плюс один. Т.е. именно один раз. Нужно сравнивать не на равенство, а на неравенство.

```
while (!myWord.equals(stringBuilder))
```

Comment: по поводу логики алгоритма не буду спорить, но символ "!" не решил вопрос.

Comment: Что означает не решил?

Comment: Не решил это значит, что весь мой экран засыпало повторяющимся английским алфавитом.

Comment: а при принудительном остонавливании программы выдаёт :" Process finished with exit code -1"

Comment: Проблему из вопроса - решил.